# How to optimize Firebase hosting for http/1.x

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I use Firebase hosting to host my Single Page App.

I have two versions of my websites :

- one optimized for https/1.x
- one optimized for https/2

Firebase hosting is now using https/2. But how to optimize the website for the people still using a browser who only support https/1.x? Knowing that, as of today, there is still 20% of the browser who don't support https/2.

Comment: You'll have to make tradeoffs -- you could consider bundling assets but in smaller bundles to reduce but not completely eliminate round trips.

I've added you as a +1 to an internal feature request to offer better capabilities here.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Okay, thank you!